# Hide all references to framework cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

For security purposes id like to hide all references to the CakePHP framework that I have used to build my site. Can anyone offer any help on the best way to go about this pls? so far Google hasn't yielded any useful results.

Comment: "For security purposes..." no that is not how security works

Comment: security through obscurity isn't the best security choice, so I hope you are implementing other security meassures. Besides that, to help you we need more detail. What do you like to hide? What references? Links, error messages with "cake" on it, comments on code?

Comment: What references? Assuming you've created a custom layout that hasn't got the "powered by CakePHP" icon in it and your app isn't in debug mode, there aren't *that* much pointers that it's made with Cake by default.

Comment: Just change the favicon, add your custom error pages and disable debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real, non-sarcastic answer is:

There's absolutely no reason to hide the fact that your app was built in CakePHP - for security purposes, or any other purposes. Just don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

For debug mode 2 (which you must have for a production site) as far as i have seen only cookie has a mention of cakephp which you can remove simply using

> ```
> Configure::write('Session.cookie', YourCustomCookieName);
> ```